Unable to start embedded Tomcat server when upgrade from 9.0.69 to 9.0.83
The project is upgrading Tomcat from 9.0.69 to 9.0.83 for solving a CVE.
The only changes are:

version number in dependency-versions.gradle to 9.0.83
adding api("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:$tomcat") in build.gradle

Version details:

OpenJDK 8 version 8.392.08-r1
Spring Boot version 2.6.8
It is a docker environment with base image of Alpine Linux 3.17.2

Errors encountered:
ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
... ...
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:229) ~[spring-boot-2.6.8.jar!/:2.6.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.WebServerManager.start(WebServerManager.java:55) ~[spring-boot-2.6.8.jar!/:2.6.8]
... ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:235) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
... ...
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1042) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
... ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:107) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:236) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
... ...
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
        at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200) ~[na:1.8.0_392]
        at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:157) ~[na:1.8.0_392]
        at java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:130) ~[na:1.8.0_392]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getParameters(SSLUtilBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getTrustManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:472) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:268) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:105) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
        ... 35 common frames omitted

Based on the error the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty, we have checked:

trustStore exists and trustStorePassword is correct to access the trustStore. File access permissions did not change.
Checked keystore secrets aren't empty or corrupted.

Tried some solutions from the below StackOverflow posts for these common errors, including:

ran the command which updated some certificates but the issue still exists.

sudo update-ca-certificates -f


checked not having the configuration server.ssl.trust-store

StackOverflow posts checked:

Error - trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty on Linux, or why is the default truststore empty

Since nothing has changed except the Tomcat version, one of our suspicions is Spring 2.6.8 version compatibility issue with Tomcat 9.0.83.
Any suggestions are appreciated! Thanks!

The current version of Spring Boot 2 is 2.7.18, not 2.6.8. See doc. Current version of Java 8 is at least 8u412b08, not 8.392.08-r1.
